# Make a new array with items derived from another array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, type-conversion

Given a PostgreSQL `ARRAY` of items of one type, how can I create a new array where each item is derived from the items in the initial array?

Example: I have an array of `INTERVAL` values. I want a new array where each item is a `NUMERIC(10, 1)` that is the total number of seconds in the corresponding `INTERVAL` value.

I know how to convert one `INTERVAL` value:

```sql
foo=> SELECT '00:01:20.000'::INTERVAL AS duration_interval;
 duration_interval 
-------------------
 00:01:20
(1 row)

foo=> SELECT extract(EPOCH FROM date_trunc('second', '00:01:20.000'::INTERVAL))
    ::NUMERIC(10, 1) AS duration_seconds;
 duration_seconds 
------------------
             80.0
(1 row)
```

The array does not exist in a table – this is a value returned from another function call – so the conversion code needs to operate on it as an array.

How can I **convert an array** of `INTERVAL` values to an array of corresponding `NUMERIC` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `unnest()` the array, do the conversion and then aggregate back into an array.

Assuming you want to do this on a real table with a primary key:

```
SELECT pk, array_agg(extract(epoch from dur_int)::numeric(10,1)
                     ORDER BY ordinality) AS duration_seconds
FROM my_table, unnest(duration_interval) WITH ORDINALITY d(dur_int)
GROUP BY pk;
```

If you have a single array, such as the result from a function call:

```
SELECT array_agg(extract(epoch from dur_int)::numeric(10,1)
                 ORDER BY ordinality) AS duration_seconds
FROM unnest(function(...)) WITH ORDINALITY d(dur_int);
```

Note that you need the [`WITH ORDINALITY` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) when unnesting the array. This will add a column `ordinality` to the result such that every row has two columns: `(dur_int interval, ordinality bigint)`. When [putting the array back again](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) with seconds instead of an interval, you order the rows by the `ordinality` column. That way you ensure that the order in the resulting array of seconds is the same as in the original array of intervals. (In general, SQL row sources have no specific ordering, the server may present rows in any order it prefers.)

If you have access to the function and you are not breaking other uses of it, you might be better off by changing the function such that you can use its result directly.

Comment: Thanks. No, this is not on a table; it's an operation I want to do on an array returned by another function.

Comment: I expanded the answer by showing how to do it on the result of a function call.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a primary key then [@Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42408131/131874) answer is enough. If not then use `row_number` to aggregate on:

```
with i(i) as (values
    (array['00:01:20.000','00:00:30.000']::interval[]),
    (array['00:02:10.000','00:01:30.000']::interval[])
)
select array_agg(extract(epoch from a)::numeric(10,1))
from (
    select i, row_number() over() as r
    from i
) s, unnest(i) a (a)
group by r
;
  array_agg   
--------------
 {80.0,30.0}
 {130.0,90.0}
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of single-letter names – `i`, `s`, etc. – can you instead name those terms so it's clear what they mean?

Comment: Use `unnest() WITH ORDINALITY` to ensure array ordering is maintained.